# Problem if I run a process for second time, increase in memory usage c#

Tags: c#, memory, process

My problem is that the first process get executed in max under a second and will consume about 20MB and will come down back to normal, but every time I restart the process after that, even an hours later it will take about 1 minute to do the work and will spike the memory over 1,200MB and will not go down after that.
The only workaround is to restart the application after each use.

```
using (var compiler = new Process
                        {
                            StartInfo =
                            {
                                FileName = _installPath + @"\Papyrus Compiler\PapyrusCompiler.exe",
                                Arguments = $@"{(string) tab.Tag} -f=""TESV_Papyrus_Flags.flg"" -i=""{_installPath}\Data\scripts\source"" -o=""{_installPath}\Data\scripts""",
                                UseShellExecute = false,
                                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                                RedirectStandardError = true,
                                CreateNoWindow = true
                            }
                        })
                        {
                            compiler.Start();

                            Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
                            Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

                            compiler.WaitForExit();
                        }
```

Thank's for the help in advance.

Edit:
Made a few change but didn't help at all

```
using (var compiler = new Process
                    {
                        StartInfo =
                        {
                            FileName = _installPath + @"\Papyrus Compiler\PapyrusCompiler.exe",
                            Arguments = $@"{tab.Tag as string} -f=""TESV_Papyrus_Flags.flg"" -i=""{_installPath}\Data\scripts\source"" -o=""{_installPath}\Data\scripts""",
                            UseShellExecute = false,
                            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                            RedirectStandardError = true,
                            CreateNoWindow = true
                        }
                    })
                    {
                        string eOut = null;
                        compiler.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                        {
                            eOut += e.Data;
                        };

                        compiler.Start();

                        compiler.BeginErrorReadLine();
                        var ou = compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                        compiler.WaitForExit();

                        Console.WriteLine(eOut);
                        Console.WriteLine(ou);
                    }
```

Also the thing I didn't mention the first time the console is redirect to a textbox

```
        readonly TextWriter _writer;

    public Form1(string args)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Instantiate the writer
        _writer = new TextBoxStreamWriter(output);
        // Redirect the out Console stream
        Console.SetOut(_writer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so long and puling my hair of I decided to try something else to resolve the problem.
I created a new application with only this method with a button click to test if it would hang on the second attempt to compile the script. My surprise was that the problem was gone.

I decide then to try to reproduce my error by adding a few more actions from the original application. As soon I added the output.Clear(); it started to hang, problem found

I also tried to do output.Text = ""; and it will still started to hang.